# Has anyone heard of the "Of" operator, and if yes then what does it represent?

Tags: mnemonic

Where I studied (India), in my school we were taught BODMAS as Brackets, Of, Division, Multi, Add, Sub.

With "Of" being the Of operator as in
1/2 Of 4  ie. Literally - 1/2 parts of 4
Can also be represented as (1/2)(4)
which is sorta multiplication but always takes preference before division.
But coming across some westerners either they don't use Bodmas and mainly the Of operator. Its instead Exponents/indices

And if you're asking about exponents, we always consider them part of the numbers and it came as second nature to solve them when moving forward wouldn't be possible without it, in other words before DMAS.

So now it seems to me that the "Of" and Exponents tie in for the second place, but if I were to include both, it would be BEODMAS or BIODMAS
4 parts of 4² should be solve as
4 Of 4² = 4 Of 16 = 64
Or
(4)(4²) = (4)(16) = 64

But all these is useless if no one remembers the Of operator, or I have been hallucinating for the past 12 years of my education

[What does O stand for in the BODMAS](http://www.notjustsums.co.uk/2015/02/what-does-o-stand-for-in-bodmas.html?m=1)
This article adds even more to the confusion

Comment: "Of" *is* multiply.

Comment: David P, I'll take that as my answer and end it here concluding I've always understood it wrong for the past decade